# fadein background color on hover using CSS

Tags: css

This pretty simple JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/sj2Kn/) changes the background colour of a block on 'hover', but how do I get it to fadein/fadeout?

```
.block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
.block:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property

```
.block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s; /* For webkits */
    transition: background .5s;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sj2Kn/4/)</kbd>

The property is simple, the first parameter you pass is the property you want to animate, so say you want to animate the `height` you can pass the `height` or you can use `all` as the value if you want to transit all the properties which are transitional, and the next parameter is the time we set for the transition, you can set as `1s`, `2s` and so on where `S` stands for *seconds*.

---

It's worth noting that the property am using is a short hand property for the following properties

```
transition-delay: 0s
transition-duration: 0s
transition-property: background
transition-timing-function: ease
```

Where in the above example we are using the `transition-property` and `transition-duration`, default values are used for other properties.

Answer (score 3):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/sj2Kn/1/)

Add `transition:background 200ms ease-in;` to `.block`

```
.block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    transition:background 200ms ease-in;
}
```

Where `200ms` is the amount of time you wish the fade to take.

The CSS property `transition` defines you want an animation to take place, the three following parts are the specific property you want to transition (can be set to  `all`), the speed, and the [**animation timing function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function).

[**More on CSS transitions from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

> CSS transitions, which are part of the CSS3 set of specifications,
>   provide a way to control animation speed when changing CSS properties.
>   Instead of having property changes take effect immediately, you can
>   cause the changes in a property to take place over a period of time.
>   For example, if you change the color of an element from white to
>   black, usually the change is instantaneous. With CSS transitions
>   enabled, changes occur at time intervals that follow an acceleration
>   curve, all of which can be customized.

Comment: difference of milliseconds :D

Comment: I'm guessing it is better, for compatibility, to include the -webkit- variation as well?

Comment: @Andy - you can do, depends what you're trying to support, though Chrome doesnt require it (latest)

Answer (score 1):

## [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/orahmax/sj2Kn/3/)

```
  .block {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        transition: all 0.25s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    }
    .block:hover {
        background-color: #333;
        transition: all 0.25s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    }
```

Comment: You need to use transitions for both hover and default. Plus, make sure u add browser support prefixes(-moz, -webkit).

Comment: Interesting, what is the importance of including for both hover and default?

Comment: @Andy remove transition from default in fiddle and know thyself

Comment: I'm voting that comment up simply for the fact you used the word "thyself". ;)

Comment: Using IE, your code works without the lines of transition code under .block:hover.